# How to share datatype declaration with SML and CM

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am a bit confused about using definitions from one SML file in another SML file in a SML project that I compile with CM. It seems like `A.sml` can only use signature and structure definitions from `B.sml` if they have been declared in the `project.cm` file.

I want to declare a `datatype MyType = MyConstr {name:string, other: string}` in `B.sml`, and construct values of that type `MyType` in `A.sml`. If I understand the CM docs right, I can only export structures, signatures, functors and functor signatures. This sounds fairly limiting in terms of code reuse.

Now, does that mean that my `MyType` would need to be part of a structure of signature, so that I can use it from another module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that (at the top level) you can only export modules, but this doesn't mean you can only use signature and structure definitions in one file if they're described in a `.cm` file---just that they need be mentioned there either directly or indirectly via `source(-)` (or similar) to be used externally to the library.

Supposing you have some module in `A.sml` that you'd like to use in `B.sml` and your only goal is to expose `structure Foo` from `B.sml`, then something like

```
Library
    structure Foo
is
    A.sml
    B.sml
```

should suffice. You may also want to read sections 2.5 and 2.6 of the [CM documentation](https://www.smlnj.org/doc/CM/new.pdf) (pp. 8-9) if you haven't already.